# Selenium JSON Wire Protocol vs Webdriver Wire Protocol

Tags: json, selenium-webdriver, migration, protocols, w3c

I have seen that the[**`JSON Wire Protocol`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) is obsolete and the [**`Webdriver Wire Protocol`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#privacy) is the new implementation.

I want to understand what changes to implement in the [**`Webdriver Wire Protocol`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#privacy) and how it is different from  the [**`JSON Wire Protocol`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are the naming conventions that have changed:

```
JSON Wire Protocol 		 WebDriver Wire Protocol
version 			 browserVersion
platform 			 platformName
noProxy 			 noproxy
UnknownCommand 			 unknown command
NoSuchFrame 			 no such frame
NoSuchElement 			 no such element
StaleElementReference 		 stale element reference
ElementIsNotSelectable 		 element not selectable
JavaScriptError 		 javascript error
Timeout 			 timeout
NoSuchWindow 			 no such window
InvalidCookieDomain 		 invalid cookie domain
ScriptTimeout  			 script timeout
SessionNotCreatedException 	 session not created
MoveTargetOutOfBounds 		 move target out of bounds
NoAlertOpenError 		 no such alert
InvalidElementCoordinates 	 invalid coordinates
stackTrace 			 stacktrace
```

Error codes and data structures have changed as well. See references for implementation details.

Version history of both APIs is detailed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276430/1113772).

**References**

- [Relationships between different versions of Selenium - Yi Zeng](http://yizeng.me/2014/04/25/relationships-between-different-versions-of-selenium/)
- [Selenium Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md)
- [Selenium Issue #3551: Wire Protocol Documentation Issues](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3551)
- [W3C Living Document: WebDriver Protocol](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html)
- [Selenium Wiki: JSON Wire Protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol)