# What is mean by webdriver W3C protocol. How it is different from JSon protocol

Tags: selenium, webdriver

What is W3c Web driver Protocol. How it is different from Json wire protocol. Why selenium is changed from Json wire protocol to W3c web driver protocol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium JSON Wire Protocol vs Webdriver Wire Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856694/selenium-json-wire-protocol-vs-webdriver-wire-protocol)

Answer (score 0):

The differences have been detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856694/selenium-json-wire-protocol-vs-webdriver-wire-protocol/40165560#40165560).

> Here are the naming conventions that have changed:
>
> ```
> **JSON Wire Protocol**      **WebDriver Wire Protocol**
> version                     browserVersion
> platform                    platformName
> noProxy                     noproxy
> UnknownCommand              unknown command
> NoSuchFrame                 no such frame
> NoSuchElement               no such element
> StaleElementReference       stale element reference
> ElementIsNotSelectable      element not selectable
> JavaScriptError             javascript error
> Timeout                     timeout
> NoSuchWindow                no such window
> InvalidCookieDomain         invalid cookie domain
> ScriptTimeout               script timeout
> SessionNotCreatedException  session not created
> MoveTargetOutOfBounds       move target out of bounds
> NoAlertOpenError            no such alert
> InvalidElementCoordinates   invalid coordinates
> stackTrace                  stacktrace
> ```
>
> Error codes and data structures have changed as well. See references
>   for implementation details.
>
> Version history of both APIs is detailed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276430/selenium-webdriver-and-selenium-server).
>
> [References Relationships between different versions of Selenium - Yi
>   Zeng](https://yizeng.me/2014/04/25/relationships-between-different-versions-of-selenium/)
>
> [Selenium Changelog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/CHANGES.md)
>
> [Selenium Issue #3551: Wire Protocol Documentation Issues](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3551)
>
> [W3C Living Document: WebDriver Protocol](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/)
>
> [Selenium Wiki: JSON Wire Protocol](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol)

Comment: If you know the question has been answered already, it's best to mark the question as a duplicate. Posting the answer here just makes two copies of the same question.